# how to create a drill down table in erb - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have 2 tables in my database, Companies & Users. I have one list (displayed as table) which lists out all the companies. Now I want to insert a link in the each row which could take the user to another list (displayed as table) which shows only those users belonging to the particular company row ?

```
Companies list

<table>
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= company.Name %></td>
    <td><%= company.addressline1 %></td>
    <td><%= company.addressline2 %></td>
    <td><%= company.City %></td>
    <td><%= company.postcode %></td>
    <td><%= company.Telephone %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_company_path(company) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Users", url_for(:users) %></td>  
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Users list

```
<table>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= UserType.find(user.user_type_id).user_type_name %></div>
    <td><%= check_box_tag(user, user.is_admin, user.is_admin) %></div>
    <td><%= check_box_tag(user, user.active_status, user.active_status) %></div>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit',  edit_user_path(user) %></td>
  </tr>
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.  You can start by adding a simple route:

```
match 'companies/:company_id/users' => 'users#for_company', :as => :company_users
```

And in your `UsersController`:

```
def for_company
  @users = Company.find(params[:company_id]).users
  render :action => :index
end
```

And in your companies list view change the link to:

```
<td><%= link_to "Users", company_users_path(company) %></td>
```

Once you have this in place and working, you may want to consider alternative ways to setup the route.  For instance, you might want `users` to be a nested resource under `companies`.  See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info on this.

Comment: why do you think its better to use nested resource ?

Comment: If nesting truly reflects your domain, it is much cleaner to reflect that throughout the application, including building urls and navigation.  If this drill down is a one-off case however, there probably won't be much benefit to nesting.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012728/how-to-create-a-new-record-or-update-if-a-particular-record-based-on-an-attribut

Answer (score 0):

Pinny's answer will work but if you're scoping your users over a company you may want to look in to nested resources (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

You can define your users resource as a 'child' of companies in your `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :companies do
  resources :users
end
```

From then on you always have the parameter :company_id available in your users controller which will be accessible through `/companies/#{company_id}/users`

In your controller you could then scope any users query over the company, for example:

```
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @user = @company.users.find(params[:id])
end
```