# How to create a new record or update if a particular record based on an attribute other than record id exists, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 model classes, employee & company. Only an employee id is generated by an external library. I am trying to update an employee details if his details already exist, else I need to create a new employee details. following is the code for create method:

```
def create

 if !@emp= Details.find_or_create_by_emp_id(params[:details][:emp_id])
    @emp = Details.new(params[:details])

  // some logic goes here 


  else
    @emp.update_attributes(params[:details])
    render action: "show"
  end      
end
```

But this always creates a new record with existing emp_id, rather than updating the table row pertaining to a specific emp_id. How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def create
  @emp = Details.find_by_emp_id(params[:details][:emp_id])

  if @emp
    @emp.update_attributes(params[:details])
    render action: "show"
  else
    @emp = Details.new(params[:details])
    //other stuff
  end
end
```

So if the employee already exists it's set to @emp, otherwise @emp is set to nil

Comment: Details.find_by_emp_id(params[:details][:emp_id]) is not evaluating to true, is it correct syntax ?

Comment: You could try `@emp = Details.where("emp_id = ?", params[:details][:emp_id])` then change the if statement to `if @emp.any? @emp.first.update_attributes.....`

Comment: No, I am not sure update_attributes is the right approach. still it creates newer employee detail rows for the same emp_id

Answer (score 0):

You're using find_or_create wrong. It takes both the identifier and the hash:

```
 if Detail.find_or_create_by_emp_id(params[:detail][:emp_id], params[:detail])
   #success
 else
   #fail
 end
```

Note: both your Model name and param seems to be plural, that's against convention, are you sure that's what you intended?